# How to use FQDN instead of just the host part at command prompt?

Tags: 14.04, command-line, prompt

My current Ubuntu 14.04 command prompt is like username@host being the server FQDN host.domain.com but I want the command prompt be username@host.domain.com. How I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open your `~/.bashrc`.

Find this:

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
```

And replace `\h` with `\H`, like this:

```
if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\H\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\H:\w\$ '
fi
```

`\h` is the short-hostname, and `\H` is the FQDN.

Comment: You can find .bashrc for root at /root  i.e.  "sudoedit /root/.bashrc" will change it for user root, too.